# understanding pointwise convergence a.e. in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm going through a proof and the assumptions are that $\mu$ is a complete measure and that $f_n\rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. One of the lines in the proof says

If $f_n\rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e., then $f=\displaystyle \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ $\mu$-a.e.

I thought that $f_n\rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e. only tells us $f=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ $\mu$-a.e. Maybe I just don't understand $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as well as I thought. Could someone clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: If a limit exists (of anything), then
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n$$
and if it doesn't,
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n$$

Comment: @AlexR Of course, you want strict inequality in the last line.

Comment: @DavidMitra considering "if it doesn't", yes. But too late to edit and it's not technically wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

As AlexR pointed out, if $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, then in particular $a=\limsup_n a_n$ (go back to the definition of convergence and the $\limsup$).

Then use this reasoning for the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\geqslant 1}$ where $x$ is in the set $C$ of full measure where the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise.